# Merging time series with different number of observations where variables have the same name (SAS)

Tags: loops, merge, macros, time-series, renaming

I have a bunch of time series data (sas-files) which I like to merge / combine up to a larger table (I am fairly new to SAS).

1. Filenames: 
   cq_ts_SYMBOL, where SYMBOL is the respective symbol for each file
2. with the following structure:

cq_ts_AAA.sas7bdat: file1

```
SYMBOL   DATE        TIME         BID     ASK      MID
AAA      20100101    9:30:00      10.375  10.4      .
AAA      20100101    9:31:00      10.38   10.4      .
.
.
AAA      20150101    15:59:00     15      15.1      .
```

cq_ts_BBB.sas7bdat: file2

```
SYMBOL   DATE        TIME         BID     ASK      MID
BBB      20120101    9:30:00      12.375  12.4      .
BBB      20120102    9:31:00      12.38   12.4      .
.
.
BBB      20170101    15:59:00     20      20.1      .
```

Key characteristics:
- They have the same variable name
- They have different number of observations
- They are all saved in the same folder

So what I want to do is:
- Create 3 tables: BID-table, ASK-table, Mid-table with the following structure, ie for bid-table, cq_ts_bid.sas7bdat:

```
DATE        TIME         AAA     BBB     ...
20100101    9:30:00      10.375   .
20100102    9:31:00      10.38    .
.
.
20120101    9:30:00      9.375  12.375
20120102    9:31:00      9.38   12.38
.
.
20150101    15:59:00     15      17
.
.
20170101    15:59:00     .       20
```

It is not all to difficult to do it for 2 stock time series, however, I was wondering whether there is the possibility to do the following:

1. From data set cq_ts_AAA take DATE TIME BID and rename BID to AAA (either from the values in symbol? does this make sense? or get the name from the filename).
2. Do the same for cq_ts_BBB.
3. In fact, loop through the folder to get the number of files and filenames (this part I got more or less, see below).
4. Merge cq_ts_BBB and cq_ts_BBB having DATE TIME AAA (former bid price of AAA) BBB (former bid price of BBB), for all the files in the folder.
5. Do this for BID, then for ASK and finally MID (actually I couldn't get the midpoint variable from bid and ask (i.e. mid= (bid + ask) / 2;) just gives me the "." in the previous data steps when creating the files).

I think a macro to first get each single file then rename (when should this step take place?) it and merge them together - like a double loop.

Here the renaming and merging part:

```
data ALDW_short (rename=(iprice = ALDW));
     set output.cq_ts_aldw
retain date time ALJ;
run;

data ALJ_short (rename= (iprice = ALJ));
set output.cq_ts_alj;
retain date time datetime ALJ;
run;

data ALDW_ALJ_merged (keep= date itime ALDW ALJ);
    merge ALDW_short ALJ_short;
    by datetime;
run;
```

This is the part to loop through the folder and get a list of names:

```
proc contents data = output._all_ out = outputcont(keep = memname) noprint;
run;

proc sort data = outputcont nodupkey;
by memname;
run;

data _null_;
set outputcont end = last;
by memname;
i+1;
call symputx('name'||trim(left(put(i,8.))),memname);
if last then call symputx('count',i);
run;
```

Would it make sense to extract the symbol (and how? they have different length) from the filename or just to take them from the variable SYMBOL (and how can I get the one value to rename my column?)?

Somehow I have difficulty changing the order of columns, ie. I tried with retain and format.

Comment: Why?   Why do you want take the value of Symbol out of a variable and turn it in the name of a variable instead?  Your original structure looks good to me.  You can always just use PROC REPORT to make a report with the symbol values as the column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could do this easily with `PROC TRANSPOSE`.  Combine your datasets into a single dataset.

```
data all ;
  set set output.cq_ts_: ;
  by date time;
run;
```

Then use PROC TRANSPOSE for each of your source variables/target tables.

```
proc transpose data=all out=bid ;
   by date time ;
   id symbol; 
   var bid;
run;
```

Given your example data a formula for MID of

```
mid = (bid + ask)/2 ;
```

Should work.  Most likely if you got all missing values you probable put the assignment statement before the SET or INPUT statement. In other words you were trying to calculate using values that had not been read in yet.

Comment: Dear Tom, as my Latin teacher used to say: All road leads to Rome; and you have just found me the private jet flight straight there!

During the Would you recommend - based on efficiency - to create a new variable during the first data set step, i.e. datetime = dhms(date,0,0,time); and then transpose or first transpose and then create the new variable? and also create my mid variable (mid = (bid + ask) / 2;)?

Comment: not sure how to edit the comment above, but: please disregard the last questions.

Comment: You can only edit comments for a little while. But you can delete them and enter new ones.